# Access C# method using ajax in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Below are both my C#  and

JavaScript code, I can access this method but I'm not getting the expected output

from "success":

```
success: function( msg ){ 
    alert( msg.d );  
}
```

Instead it returns [object object]

Javascript:

```
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Home.aspx/UpdateSelectionStatus,
                data: '{id_ver: "' + id + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(msg){alert(msg.d);},
                failure: function(){ }
            });
```

C#:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
    public static string UpdateSelectionStatus(string id_ver){

      return "success" + id_ver;

   }
```

Comment: please return json value from c# function like this  return "{\"success\":\""+id_ver+"\"}";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function( msg ){ 
    alert( msg.d.toString());  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That is the bug:

```
  alert(msg.d);
```

just use  msg directly:

```
  success: function (msg) {alert(msg); },
```

You returned a simple string, not a complex type, so you haven't got any property like "d".

Comment: Have you debugged? How does msg object look like in chrome or firebug debugger? Is it null, or has it got any member? If it returns in success callback, there is no problem with c# code and ajax call. Problem is in callback.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code: it is working at my end.

```
 var vid = 10;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home.aspx/UpdateSelectionStatus",
            data: "{id_ver:'" + + vid + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });
```